# Strings/Arguments for a new person

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need help with a command, for example, if someone writes
 " !report @user Spamming " How can I do so my discord account gets a message from the bot about =
Who reports who and for what reason

I've tried watching videos and posts but I can't get my head around it

```
  client.on('message', async function(message)  {

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "report")) {
      const user = await client.fetchUser(args[1].match(/^<@!?(\d+)>$/)[1]); 
      if (!user) return message.channel.send('Oops! Please mention a valid user.');

      const reason = args.slice(2).join(' ');

      const me = await client.fetchUser('123456890'); //My id

      me.send(`${message.author} reported ${user} for: \`${reason}\``)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));



      }
     }
  )
```

I want for example
In channel = !report @patrick#4245 He is spamming
Then The bot sends a message to me 
@fadssa#2556 Reported @patrick#4245 Reason = He is spamming

Comment: Please include your code, example input, and expected/actual output and any errors outputted.

Answer (score 0):

Before just copying this code, let's actually think this through...

1. So, let's start by first getting everything we need for the message. First, we should retrieve a User from the argument provided. We do this by comparing the string to that of a mention and picking out the ID. If one doesn't exist, we return an error telling the user to mention someone.
2. Now, assuming you already have your arguments declared (if not, see [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#number-ranges) to help), we can simply put together the arguments used for the reason. To do so, we should use [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and then join those words with [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
3. Then, since we want the bot to send you a DM, we'll have to find you in the Discord world. For this, we can use [`client.fetchUser()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=fetchUser).
4. Now, we can just send you the DM and you'll be alerted of all reports.

```js
/*
* Should be placed within your command's code, after checking required arguments exist
* Assuming 'client' is the Discord Client and 'args' is the array of arguments
* Must be within an async function to use 'await'
*/

const user = await client.fetchUser(args[1].match(/^<@!?(\d+)>$/)[1]); // see below
if (!user) return message.channel.send('Oops! Please mention a valid user.');

const reason = args.slice(2).join(' ');

const me = await client.fetchUser('189855563893571595'); // replace with your ID

me.send(`${message.author} reported ${user} for: \`${reason}\``))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

*Although it may look confusing, using regex is a much better option than `message.mentions`. There's plenty of whack examples where seemingly perfect code will not return the expected user, so this is why I would definitely choose retrieving the ID from a mention myself.*

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the good and long answer, i really appreciate it! I just don't understand right now,

Comment: Instead of declaring a new async function, with what I can deduce from your current setup you can simply declare the message event's function as async like so: `client.on('message', async message => {...})` (ES6) or `client.on('message', async function(message) {...})`.

Comment: It also sais, " client is not defined "

Comment: Okay i changed it to bot.on (because i have "const bot = new Discord.Client();") and now it dosnt say client not defined but it still dosnt happen anything with the command

Comment: In the code provided from this answer, make sure to change `client` to `bot` as well.

Comment: Okay i did but i feel like i have done something wrong because nothing happens when i write " *report " in chat or anything

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: args is not defined

Comment: Make sure you [parse your arguments](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html) before this code.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand that explainment the text gave me

Comment: In your `message` event, declare your arguments like so: `const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g)`.